# Calendar Start and End Dates not correct

Tags: calendar, calculated-column, date-time

I am having trouble with out SharePoint calendar. I have some calculated columns set up to display start and end times for anything that is not an all day event (based off the guide [here](http://itblog.wolthaus.net/2011/05/using-calculated-column-to-display-sharepoint-calendar/comment-page-1/#comment-192)), but some items are displaying start and end times even when they are set to all day events.

After looking into this over the last couple of days, I created a calculated column simply set to:

```
=[Start Date]
```

and all items are showing the wrong time.

For example, I have one item which has a start time of 9/09/2013 12:00 AM, but the test calculated column is showing 9/09/2013 10:00 AM.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Edit: I just had a thought, I am in Australia (GMT +10), could this be having an effect on the way our times/dates are being stored?

Comment: I have also tested this on another calendar on a different subsite and the same behaviour is displayed

Answer (score 1):

I found this formula on another site, since SharePoint 2013 also has the issue of not reporting a Start Date (date only format) correctly (still rounding back one day when set up as an all day event).

I updated the "dd mmm yyyy" to reflect in the format I needed for my calendar summary view.  Hope this helps someone.

=TEXT(IF([End Time]=[Start Time],[Start Time],IF(MOD(ROUNDUP(([End Time]-[Start Time])*24,0),24)=0,[Start Time]+1,[Start Time])),"dd mmm yyyy")